# Significance of CRC while comparing class files

Tags: class, crc, beyondcompare

What does CRC mean while comparing two files?

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly from the [Beyond Compare's](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_crc) website:

> A CRC is a 4-byte mathematical checksum of a file's contents.  If a
>   pair of files have different CRCs, then you can be sure their contents
>   are different.  If they have matching CRCs, then it's likely (but not
>   certain) that their contents match.